# jQuery - find if text exists inside an iFrame

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I'm using an jQuery wysiwyg editor plugin  on one of my textareas inside a form and I want o apply validation to it. The wysiwyg jQuery plugin is generating an `iframe` so I need to detect `if there is any text inserted` `inside the iframe` not the text area.

```
<div class="wysiwyg" style="width: 581px;">
<ul class="panel" role="menu">
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<iframe id="id_message_bodyIFrame" frameborder="0" src="javascript:false;" style="min-height: 170px; width: 573px;" tabindex="0">
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
my text I want to find if exists
<br _moz_dirty="">
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
</div>
<textarea id="id_message_body" title="Please add a message on the text box above." name="message_body" cols="70" rows="10" style="display: none;"></textarea>
<div id="req_message_body" class="req" style="display: none;">This is required</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas how to find if text has been inserted inside the iframe and create a error message next to it like `<div id="err"> This field is required</div>`? I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#id_message_bodyIFrame').contents().find('body').text()
```

that will give you text then you can just add

```
.length()
```

to the end to test how long it is

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. So to check if text has been added inside the frame should I do something like this?if($('#id_message_bodyIFrame').contents().find('body').text().length()<0){ //do something }

Comment: I'll let you know as soon as I test it.